# Move 32bit register into a 8 bit register

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, cpu-registers

Im trying to move `edx` into `al` but i get this error

```
lib/io/print.asm:50: error: invalid combination of opcode and operands
```

this is the code

```
mov edx, 0x41
mov al, edx
```

thanks in advance

Comment: EDX is a 32-bit register. DX is the lower 16-bits of EDX, and DH is the upper 8 bits of DX and DL is the lower 8 bits of DX. You could do `mov dl, 0x41` `mov al, dl` or `mov edx, 0x41` `mov al, dl`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the second line:

```
mov al, edx
```

The `edx` register is 32-bits, but `al` is 8-bit, so you can't directly move one into the other. If you want to move the low 8 bits of `edx` into `dl`, do this:

```
mov al, dl
```

Or perhaps you want to move all of `edx` into `eax`, like this:

```
mov eax, edx
```

The difference is the first option leaves the high 24 bits of `eax` unchanged, while the second option sets them to the same as the corresponding bits of `edx`.

If you don't care about the high 24 bits, e.g., because you aren't going to use them, or because you know they are zero in either case, the second option may be slightly faster because it breaks the dependency on the previous value of `eax`, so it can execute as soon as `edx` is ready, regardless of what happened to `eax` before.

```
movzx eax, dl
```

MOVZX has the same benefit of avoiding a false-dependency on the AL destination, while only taking one byte from EDX and zero-extending it.  The byte you want is in AL.

If you want a different byte of the source EDX, you can move and shift, or `movzx eax, dh`.

Comment: @seva-alekseyev unforunately neither of these work, if I do

`

global _start
section .data
        string db "testing", 0x00
section .text
 _start:
        movzx edx, byte [string]
        mov eax, 4
        mov ebx, 1
        mov ecx, edx
        mov edx, 12
        int 0x80
 ...

`

It still outputs the entire string, and if I try

`
 ...
        xor eax, eax
        mov al, [string]
        xor edx, edx
        mov dl, al
    ...
        mov ecx, edx
 ...

`

It outputs nothing, I am still learning this language, any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: @JOhn - that's a separate question, not something I'm going to hash out in the comments.